# Trouble with "string.contains" function

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am writing a web form that has a unique travelID per travel request. (see blank column in picture below, I'm not high enough reputation to embed the picture in here)

[image: TravelID]

Some of the travel requests have attached documents and others do not. I wrote this code:

```
    Dim dirs As String() = Directory.GetFiles("E:\DomainWebs\Intranet\fileups\TravelDocs\")
    Dim i As Integer = 0

    For Each GridRecord As GridRecord In TravelWebDataGrid.Rows

        For Each doc As String In dirs

            If doc.Contains(TravelWebDataGrid.Rows(i).Items(10).Value) = True Then

                TravelWebDataGrid.Rows(i).Items(11).Value = True

            End If

        Next

        i += 1

    Next
```

Just for testing, only the top Travel Request has documents attached. As you can see, it is checking the second row checkbox as well even though it doesn't have any documents attached.

This is what is being compared to row 2:

```
"DocName" - E:\DomainWebs\Intranet\fileups\TravelDocs\RONNIEP20180124141116-Hello.docx
"TravelID" - RONNIEP20180124135357
```

Does anyone know why it is doing this? Let me know if you need any more information. Thanks in advance for your responses.

Answer (score 0):

This might be off because I haven't worked with a datagrid but it looks like the code has been over-complicated with the counter. Can you do this?

```
' you're looping gridrecords/rows.
For Each GridRecord As GridRecord In TravelWebDataGrid.Rows
    For Each doc As String In dirs
        ' use the gridrecord here, not rows(i).
        If doc.Contains(GridRecord.Items(10).Value) = True Then
            ' and here.
            GridRecord.Items(11).Value = True
        End If
    Next
Next
```